# GORM or HSQL for left join exclusive

Tags: grails

I have Course domain,
Course has one teacher or null
I want to find all courses which either has no teacher or teacher.id != :loginId

How can I write query using GORM dynamic find* methods
Or write it using HSQL
- My teacher property is User domain

Appreciate your help

Comment: left join will capture nulls or all - with left join you will also get multiple of the same records for as many as found so you may then need to group by course.id or something

Comment: @chi nguyen - please move your update of the question in comment into the question using "edit"

Comment: What is the relationship from the Course to the Teacher? `hasOne` or `hasMany`? I assume `hasOne` because of the singular **Teacher**

Answer (score 0):

**hasOne Class Structure**

```
class Course {
    User teacher

    static hasOne = [
        teacher: User
    ]
}

class User {
    // implicit id field
}
```

**Using HQL**

```
def getCourses(def loginId) {
    return Course.executeQuery("""
        SELECT
            c
        FROM 
            Course c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN c.teacher as t
        WHERE
            (t.id = NULL OR t.id != :logIn)
    """, [loginId: loginId])
}
```

**Using CriteriaBuilder**

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

def getCourses(def loginId) {
    return Course.createCriteria().list{
        createAlias(
            "teacher", 
            "t", 
            CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN
        )

        or {
            ne("t.id", loginId)
            isNull('t.id')
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm going off of past experiences so I haven't tested your exact scenario, but I believe both options should work.  I'm under the impression that a grails dynamic finder would not work in this case because of the nested condition you need (`course.teacher.id != loginId`).

Comment: Tks tylerwal, The HQL solution is easy to understand as it like SQL. I just study some Hibernate createCriteria and createAlias to understand 2nd option, and it is great too. Both options solve my problem. Tks for your help